# Как убрать белую рамку от TitledPane

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Есть программа с GUI (JavaFX) -> http://joxi.ru/YmEgvbGcZvgREA .
Как видно на скриншоте, используется компонент TitledPane. Я изменил цвет фона, но эту белую рамку никак не могу убрать. Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
accordion.setStyle("-fx-box-border: transparent;");
```

Пояснение, почему так и как это работает [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856359/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-border-around-a-split-pane-in-javafx)

Comment: Пояснение должно быть прямо в тексте ответа без надобности ходить по ссылкам (даже если по ссылке другой stackoverlow)

Comment: @andreymal я оставил ответ на сам вопрос тут. Если человеку интересно, почему именно так - он перейдет и почитает. Если нет - то зачем ему смотреть целую стену текста теории? И к тому же, я не сторонник плодить одну и ту же информацию, если к ней можно спокойно подступиться ссылкой.